# Find the matched nodes in a tree with python

Tags: python

I have some data as:

```
nodes = [
    {'name': 'N1', 'id': 1, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': None},
    {'name': 'N2', 'id': 2, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 1},
    {'name': 'N3', 'id': 3, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 1},
    {'name': 'N4', 'id': 4, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 1},
    {'name': 'N5', 'id': 5, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 1},
    {'name': 'N6', 'id': 6, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 2},
    {'name': 'N7', 'id': 7, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 2},
    {'name': 'N8', 'id': 8, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 3},
    {'name': 'N9', 'id': 9, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 4},
    {'name': 'N10', 'id': 10, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 6},
    {'name': 'N11', 'id': 11, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 6},
    {'name': 'N12', 'id': 12, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 7},
    {'name': 'N13', 'id': 13, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 7},
    {'name': 'N14', 'id': 14, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 9},
    {'name': 'N15', 'id': 15, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 9},
    {'name': 'N16', 'id': 16, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 9},
    {'name': 'N17', 'id': 16, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 15},
]

# data maybe in different sequence
import random
random.shuffle(nodes)
```

I draw a picture for it as below:

[image: tree nodes]

I want to find the children nodes of N1 which color is 'red', it should stop when find a 'red' node in a path, which means, when it reaches to N3,  it will not continue to check N8,  Similarly, it will stop at N9 and not check N14, N15, N16 and N17.

so my expected nodes are:

```
expected_nodes = ['N3', 'N5', 'N7', 'N9', 'N10']
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Your first step should be to give this a tree-like structure in memory, where every node object has an iterable of children.  You can then write a recursive function for accumulating a list of red nodes.

Comment: @vts How have you *tried* to do this in Python? Is there any code you have tried and that you can show us?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank not homework, I have a real world use case and I translate it to such a question to be more easy for others to understand. I'm still trying this, but not work yet, anyway, I'll update this if there is no good solution before I figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend representing each node as an object of a node class; to do this, you can either make use of a dedicated library for graphs/trees, such as [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) or [`anytree`](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or implement your own `Node` class. Here is my attempt at this.

*Edit: if you want to work with your current dictionary format, e.g. because your data is already encoded like this and you don't want to migrate it, I recommend either [@A Rather Long Name's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825322/6117426) or [@blhsing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825841/6117426) solution. I've also added my own approach at the end of this answer.*

Note: I have assumed that by wanting to find "all red *children* of a node" you don't want to include the start node itself; but this can be easily modified.

## Using a custom class

### Class `Node`

Here I'll define the class `Node` as follows. A couple of important remarks: first, I implemented Nodes with information pointing to children instead of parents; second, the properties for each node are just the string `name`, the string `color`, and the tuple `children`.

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Collection, Iterable, Tuple


class Node:
    COLORS: ClassVar[Collection[str]] = ('grey', 'red')  # Allowed colors

    def __init__(self, name: str, color: str):
        self._name = name
        self.color = color
        self._children = ()  # Initialize as empty tuple

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @property
    def color(self) -> str:
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, color: str):
        """Make sure it's one of the allowed colors"""
        if color not in Node.COLORS:
            raise ValueError(f"{color} is not a valid color")
        self._color = color

    @property
    def children(self) -> Tuple['Node', ...]:
        return self._children

    @children.setter
    def children(self, children: Iterable['Node']):
        """Make sure children are nodes"""
        if not all(isinstance(c, Node) for c in children):
            raise TypeError("children must be of type Node")
        self._children = tuple(children)

    def __repr__(self):
        """For 'printing' node to stdout"""
        return f"Node(name={repr(self.name)}, color={repr(self._color)})"

    def find_first_red_children(self) -> Iterable['Node']:
        """Collect, for each path rooted here, the first red node that can be reached"""
        result = []
        for child in self.children:
            if child.color == 'red':
                result.append(child)
            else:
                result.extend(child.find_first_red_children())  # Recursive call

        return result
```

### Initialization

You can either initialize each node one by one, e.g.

```py
...
N2 = Node('N2', 'grey')
N2.children = (N6, N7)
...
```

or programmatically from the dictionary you have. Using the `nodes` list defined in the question, you could do

```
node_objects = {n['id']: Node(n['name'], n['color']) for n in nodes}
for node in nodes:
    if (parent_id := node['parent_id']) is not None:
        node_objects[parent_id].children += (node_objects[node['id']],)
```

(the code below assumes this is what you've done). Note that this is `O(n)` in time complexity.

### Test run

If we run

```py
red_nodes = node_objects[1].find_first_red_children()
print(red_nodes)
```

the output is

```
[Node(name='N10', color='red'), Node(name='N7', color='red'), Node(name='N3', color='red'), Node(name='N9', color='red'), Node(name='N5', color='red')]
```

which is what we wanted. Note the "left-to-right" ordering due to DFS.

### Algorithm for finding red children

The algorithm is defined in the `find_first_red_children` method of class Node:

```
def find_first_red_children(self) -> Iterable['Node']:
    """Collect, for each path rooted here, the first red node that can be reached"""
    result = []
    for child in self.children:
        if child.color == 'red':
            result.append(child)
        else:
            result.extend(child.find_first_red_children())  # Recursive call

    return result
```

It is a Depth-First Search (DFS) implementation. Its time complexity is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of nodes.

Note that since the "migration" from the raw dictionary format to `Node` objects is linear, this whole approach from start to finish is also `O(n)`, which is better than most other answers here.

---

## Working directly on the dictionary

If you decide to keep the dictionary format you used, you can use the following function:

```py
def find_first_red_children(node_list, start_node_id):
    # Get the start node
    if len(start_nodes := [n for n in node_list if n["id"] == start_node_id]) != 1:
        raise ValueError(f"Zero or more than one node with id {start_node_id}")
    start_node = start_nodes[0]

    # BFS
    result = []
    # Ordered dictionary of (id: node) of nodes at the current tree level:
    to_explore = OrderedDict({start_node['id']: start_node})
    while len(to_explore) > 0:
        children = [n for n in node_list if n['parent_id'] in to_explore]
        to_explore.clear()
        for n in children:
            if n['color'] == 'red':
                result.append(n)
            else:
                to_explore[n['id']] = n

    return result
```

This is an iterative Breadth-First Search approach. It doesn't require prior sorting, but it does involve iterating over the whole list of nodes for every level; still, if the height of the tree is very small in comparison to the number of nodes, it will be faster. In fact, a solution that requires previous sorting, like [@A Rather Long Name's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825322/6117426), would be `O(n*log(n))`, while this is `O(h*n)`, where `n` is the number of nodes and `h` is the height of the tree. Besides, sorting is useful if the node ID, or name, or some other attribute, is monotonically increasing with the tree level, but this might not be the case.

If we run

```
print([n['name'] for n in find_first_red_children(nodes, start_node_id=1)])
```

we get `['N3', 'N5', 'N7', 'N9', 'N10']`.

Comment: Really nice and elaborate answer, but what if the OP already has a dataset that is in the given format? Instead of iterating over it to translate to then use recursion, why not just solve the problem as is?

Comment: @ARatherLongName True, this wouldn't work if you already have a dataset in that format. But in my opinion if the OP's example was just that, an example (i.e. they didn't have a dataset yet, or the dataset was small and still 'under construction'), it would be worth switching.
Anyway, yours is an important observation, so I've edited my answer to reflect that; thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem, and congrats on your first accepted answer. You've deserved it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it would be done. Note that you might want to include your own try next time.

```
nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x['id'])
blocked = []
res = []

for node in nodes:
    parent = node['parent_id']

    # If parent is blocked,
    if parent in blocked:
        blocked.append(node['id']) # Block the node

    # Otherwise, if node is red,
    elif node['color'] == 'red':
        blocked.append(node['id']) # Block the node
        res.append(node['name'])   # And add to the result

print(res) # ['N3', 'N5', 'N7', 'N9', 'N10']
```

Comment: This doesn't work when a node is red and it's parent's parent is red too, I've updated the data and picture, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it now.

Comment: This works nicely with my data, however it doesn't work with a list of data that is not in good sequence, for example, has N17 as the first element. But this is my fault, your solution is easy and straightforward for my original question. Thanks.

Comment: @vts That makes sense. Assuming your input data isn't too big, you could just sort the array before iterating over it as a workaround. See line 1.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive approach:

```
def r(nodes, p=None):
    o = []
    for n in nodes:
        if n['parent_id'] == p:
            if n['color'] == 'red':
                o.append(n['name'])
            else:
                o += r(nodes, n['id'])
    return o
print(r(nodes))
```

This outputs:

```
['N10', 'N7', 'N3', 'N9', 'N5']
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work:

```
>>> nodes = [
...     {'name': 'N1', 'id': 1, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': None},
...     {'name': 'N2', 'id': 2, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 1},
...     {'name': 'N3', 'id': 3, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 1},
...     {'name': 'N4', 'id': 4, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 1},
...     {'name': 'N5', 'id': 5, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 1},
...     {'name': 'N6', 'id': 6, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 2},
...     {'name': 'N7', 'id': 7, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 2},
...     {'name': 'N8', 'id': 8, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 3},
...     {'name': 'N9', 'id': 9, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 4},
...     {'name': 'N10', 'id': 10, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 6},
...     {'name': 'N11', 'id': 11, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 6},
...     {'name': 'N12', 'id': 12, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 7},
...     {'name': 'N13', 'id': 13, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 7},
...     {'name': 'N14', 'id': 14, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 9},
...     {'name': 'N15', 'id': 15, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 9},
...     {'name': 'N16', 'id': 16, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 9},
... ]
>>> reds = [i for i in range(len(nodes)) if nodes[i]['color'] == 'red']
>>> reds
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14]
>>> idx = [i for i in reds if nodes[nodes[i]['parent_id']-1]['color'] == 'grey']
>>> idx
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
>>> expected_nodes = [nodes[i]['name'] for i in idx]
>>> expected_nodes
['N3', 'N5', 'N7', 'N9', 'N10']
```

Comment: This doesn't work when a node is red and it's parent's parent is red too, I've updated the data and picture, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive approach would be this:

```
nodeList = []

def adjacent(nodes, node):
    return [child for child in nodes if child['parent_id']==node['id'] and not child['id']==node['id']]


def reds(nodes, node):
    global nodeList
    if node['color']=='red':
        nodeList.append(node['name'])
        return
    else:
        children = adjacent(nodes, node)
        for child in children:
            reds(nodes, child)

reds(nodes, nodes[0])
print(nodeList)
```

Output:

```
['N10', 'N7', 'N3', 'N9', 'N5']
```

It searches from left to right until it finds a red colored node and stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code :

```
    def find_nodes(id_list,input_list):
        new_list = []
        for items in id_list:
            parent_list = list(filter(lambda x : x["parent_id"] == items["id"],input_list))     
            for dict_items in parent_list:            
                if(dict_items["color"] == "red"):
                    print(dict_items["name"])                    
                else:
                    new_list.append(dict_items)
        if(len(new_list) > 0):
            find_nodes(new_list,input_list)      


    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        input_list = []
        my_list = [
            {'name': 'N1', 'id': 1, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': None},
            {'name': 'N2', 'id': 2, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 1},
            {'name': 'N3', 'id': 3, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 1},
            {'name': 'N4', 'id': 4, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 1},
            {'name': 'N5', 'id': 5, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 1},
            {'name': 'N6', 'id': 6, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 2},
            {'name': 'N7', 'id': 7, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 2},
            {'name': 'N8', 'id': 8, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 3},
            {'name': 'N9', 'id': 9, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 4},
            {'name': 'N10', 'id': 10, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 6},
            {'name': 'N11', 'id': 11, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 6},
            {'name': 'N12', 'id': 12, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 7},
            {'name': 'N13', 'id': 13, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 7},
            {'name': 'N14', 'id': 14, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 9},
            {'name': 'N15', 'id': 15, 'color': 'red', 'parent_id': 9},
            {'name': 'N16', 'id': 16, 'color': 'grey', 'parent_id': 9},
        ]

        input_list = list(filter(lambda x : x["parent_id"] == None,my_list))
        find_nodes(input_list,my_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first create a tree to store the data, and then implement a custom generator function to find the first level of red nodes:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, args = [None, None, None]):
    self.id, self.name, self.color = args
    self.children = []
  def __contains__(self, _d:dict) -> bool:
    if not self.children and self.id != _d['parent_id']:
       return False
    return True if self.id == _d['parent_id'] else any(_d in i for i in self.children)
  def __iter__(self):
    if self.color == 'red':
      yield self.name
    else:
      for i in self.children:
        yield from i
  def insert_row(self, _row:dict) -> None:
    if _row['parent_id'] is None:
      self.__dict__.update(_row)
    else:
      if self.id == _row['parent_id']:
        self.children.append(Tree(args = [_row[i] for i in ['id', 'name', 'color']]))
      else:
         for i in self.children:
           if _row in i:
             i.insert_row(_row)
  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Tree({self.id}, {self.children})'

t = Tree()
for node in sorted(nodes, key=lambda x:x['id']):
  t.insert_row(node)

print([i for i in t])
```

Output:

```
['N10', 'N7', 'N3', 'N9', 'N5']
```

Comment: Works nicely with my original data, though doesn't work if I shuffle the list, I'll do more testing before accept this, thanks.

Comment: @vts Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I upvoted it, sorry for didn't accepted it as the answer. Maybe someone doesn't like python3? lol